# Exporting notes with formatting

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have the following macro for Microsoft Powerpoint 365 for exporting the notes into a separate `.txt` file. The problem is it excludes the bullet points from the notes which are in the notes. How can I fix this problem?

```
Sub ExportNotesText()

    Dim oSlides As Slides
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim strNotesText As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim intFileNum As Integer
    Dim lngReturn As Long

    ' Get a filename to store the collected text
    strFileName = InputBox("Enter the full path and name of file to extract notes text to", "Output file?", ActivePresentation.Path + "\notes.txt")

    ' did user cancel?
    If strFileName = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' is the path valid?  crude but effective test:  try to create the file.
    intFileNum = FreeFile()
    On Error Resume Next
    Open strFileName For Output As intFileNum
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then     ' we have a problem
        MsgBox "Couldn't create the file: " & strFileName & vbCrLf _
            & "Please try again."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Close #intFileNum  ' temporarily

    ' Get the notes text
    Set oSlides = ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSl In oSlides
        For Each oSh In oSl.NotesPage.Shapes
        If oSh.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderBody Then
            If oSh.HasTextFrame Then
                If oSh.TextFrame.HasText Then
                    strNotesText = strNotesText & "Slide: " & CStr(oSl.SlideIndex) & vbCrLf _
                    & oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Next oSh
    Next oSl

    ' now write the text to file
    Open strFileName For Output As intFileNum
    Print #intFileNum, strNotesText
    Close #intFileNum

    ' show what we've done
    ' lngReturn = Shell("NOTEPAD.EXE " & strFileName, vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```

Comment: You should probably use an actual dialog instead of an `InputBox` to get the file name. Also, does `strNotesText` contain anything that looks like bullet points? Your question could/should probably be narrowed down to the `Get the notes text` part.

Comment: It's normally "the done thing" to provide attribution for code you've copied from another source.  Personally, I'm not too cranky about it, so being that it's my code you've copied, NBD. Others might be offended. Giving credit (or blame?) where it's due is a good habit. IAC, TXT files don't typically show bullets; did you want to represent them with some other character, an asterisk perhaps?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I apologise Steve, I would normally, however, I have had this macro set for a while and could not remember the source of it

Comment: @Dan No worries; I just figured it as a "teachable moment" in case you didn't know that attribution was a matter of good netiquette.  But you did, so here endeth the lesson. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have the reference to the notes TextFrame, you can loop through its .TextRange.Paragraphs collection.

This will give you an asterisk & space & and the text of the paragraph or just the text if no bullet:

```
If .Paragraphs(x).ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Type = ppBulletUnnumbered Then
   Debug.Print "* " & .Paragraphs(x).Text
Else
   Debug.Print .Paragraphs(x).Text
End if
```

There may also be numbered or picture bullets. Let's not go there.